# limit character displayed in textview

Tags: textview, android

i want to show the text from edittext but the layout broken because  big number of character inputed .how i can limit the number of character displayed on textview

Answer (score 0):

you can try using on `Edittext actionlistener` you can count no. of text entered using `editext.getText().toString().gelLength();`

by using length of character you can control your edit text

Answer (score 0):

You can also use input text filter and implement logic in the filter depending on you business logic.

With this filter you can limit by character , by size of by anything you want. For example you can even implement something exotic like 'a' is allowed to be entered only after 'b'

Answer (score 0):

add `android:maxLength="30"` in TextView or EditText as your need.